# What is the fastest way to parse line with lots of Ints?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell for two years now and I'm still confused, whats the best (fastest) way to read tons of numbers from a single input line.
For learning I registered into hackerearth.com trying to solve every challenge in Haskell. But now I'm stuck with a challenge because I run into timeout issues. My program is just too slow for beeing accepted by the site.

Using the profiler I found out it takes 80%+ of the time for parsing a line with lots of integers. The percentage gets even higher when the number of values in the line increases.

Now this is the way, I'm reading numbers from an input line:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8

main = do
   scores <- fmap (map (fst . fromJust . C8.readInt) . C8.words) C8.getLine :: IO [Int]
```

Is there any way to get the data faster into the variable?

BTW: The biggest testcase consist of a line with 200.000 9-digits values. Parsing takes incredible long (> 60s).

Comment: Are you compiling (?) with optimizations? Also if I remember correctly i bytestring is faster than bytestring.char8. though I do not know the challenge, usually it is better to consume input while transforming it compared to reading and then  applying​ some function

Comment: Also did you look at attoparsec?

Comment: How do you arrive at 60 seconds? On my machine your code executes in about 0.3 seconds (compiled with `ghc -O0`).

Comment: FTR, it's rather insane to ever create a file with 200k integers in decimal, string form, in the first place. That's an amount you very definitely want to store in binary form.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: Don't know, how "hackerearth" compiles my code. Do you have any example for optimizations?

Comment: @n.m.: Reproduced the timings on local machines as well. Maybe your code didn't do anything with the values, e.g. summing them?

Comment: Did sum the values and print the sum.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is with 'hackerearth'.  If you're performance concerned you always want to be compiling and using optimizations.  Shelling out to some site is no exceptional case.

Comment: Repeated the test on my other machine. 0.1s including summation and printing the sum. Verified the sum is correct. What version of ghc and what compilation command are you using?

Comment: Here it is [online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_haskell_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMR3I0MS1xTzFsTmc).

Comment: I can confirm @n.m.'s results.  Your `Char8`-based implementation should be on par with a `scanf`-based C implementation. (My tests reading and summing 10 million 6-digit integers ran in 1.3 secs in C, 2.2 secs in Haskell w/ GHC 8.0.1, and only 0.6 secs in Haskell with a strict version of `sum`.  HackerEarth's old version of GHC (7.6.3) is likely to be slower, but not "60 seconds" slower.  You may wish to post a complete code example that illustrates the problem, and maybe we can help.

Comment: I got word from HackerEarth that they had issues with their platform, so everything ran very slow. Now it's running perfectly again. But back to my question: Is this really the fastest way to read huge lines with ints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always difficult to declare a particular approach "the fastest", since there's almost always some way to squeeze out more performance.  However, an approach using `Data.ByteString.Char8` and the general method you suggest should be among the fastest methods for reading numbers.  If you encounter a case where performance is poor, the problem likely lies elsewhere.

To give some concrete results, I generated a 191Meg file of 20 million 9-digit numbers, space-separate on a single line.  I then tried several general methods of reading a line of numbers and printing their sum (which, for the record, was 10999281565534666).  The obvious approach using `String`:

```
reader :: IO [Int]
reader = map read . words <$> getLine
sum' xs = sum xs -- work around GHC ticket 10992
main = print =<< sum' <$> reader
```

took 52secs; a similar approach using `Text`:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text.Read as T
readText = map parse . T.words <$> T.getLine
  where parse s = let Right (n, _) = T.decimal s in n
```

ran in 2.4secs (but note that it would need to be modified to handle negative numbers!); and the same approach using `Char8`:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
readChar8 :: IO [Int]
readChar8 = map parse . C.words <$> C.getLine
  where parse s = let Just (n, _) = C.readInt s in n
```

ran in 1.4secs.  All examples were compiled with `-O2` on GHC 8.0.2.

As a comparison benchmark, a `scanf`-based C implementation:

```
/* GCC 5.4.0 w/ -O3 */
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()
{
    long x, acc = 0;
    while (scanf(" %ld", &x) == 1) {
        acc += x;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", acc);
    return 0;
}
```

ran in about 2.5secs, on par with the `Text` implementation.

You can squeeze a bit more performance out of the `Char8` implementation.  Using a hand-rolled parser:

```
readChar8' :: IO [Int]
readChar8' = parse <$> C.getLine
  where parse = unfoldr go
        go s = do (n, s1) <- C.readInt s
                  let s2 = C.dropWhile C.isSpace s1
                  return (n, s2)
```

runs in about 0.9secs -- I haven't tried to determine why there's a difference, but the compiler must be missing an opportunity to perform some optimization of the `words`-to-`readInt` pipeline.

#### Haskell Code for Reference

Make some numbers with Numbers.hs:

```
-- |Generate 20M 9-digit numbers:
--    ./Numbers 20000000 100000000 999999999 > data1.txt

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment
import System.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do [n, a, b] <- map read <$> getArgs
          nums <- replicateM n (randomRIO (a,b))
          let _ = nums :: [Int]
          C.putStrLn (C.unwords (map (C.pack . show) nums))
```

Find their sum with Sum.hs:

```
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text.Read as T
import qualified Data.Char8 as C
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import System.Environment

-- work around https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10992
sum' xs = sum xs

readString :: IO [Int]
readString = map read . words <$> getLine

readText :: IO [Int]
readText = map parse . T.words <$> T.getLine
  where parse s = let Right (n, _) = T.decimal s in n

readChar8 :: IO [Int]
readChar8 = map parse . C.words <$> C.getLine
  where parse s = let Just (n, _) = C.readInt s in n

readHand :: IO [Int]
readHand = parse <$> C.getLine
  where parse = unfoldr go
        go s = do (n, s1) <- C.readInt s
                  let s2 = C.dropWhile C.isSpace s1
                  return (n, s2)

main = do [method] <- getArgs
          let reader = case method of
                "string" -> readString
                "text"   -> readText
                "char8"  -> readChar8
                "hand"   -> readHand
          print =<< sum' <$> reader
```

where:

```
./Sum string <data1.txt   # 54.3 secs
./Sum text   <data1.txt   # 2.29 secs
./Sum char8  <data1.txt   # 1.34 secs
./Sum hand   <data1.txt   # 0.91 secs
```